# Narrow subfigure caption in one line

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I have the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,automata}
\title{Tree}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
\centering
\subfigure[$b^T e = 1$]  
{
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node[rectangle,draw,color=red] {} [grow'=up];
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\hspace{5em}
\subfigure[ $b^T e = 1$ ]
{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \node[circle,draw] {} [grow'=up];
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! Great first question MWE, make sure to indent \end{document} so it properly appears as part of the code, and please explain your question in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

Your picture in `subfigure` is to narrow, that caption below it -- which is in your case accommodate to figure width -- can be fit in one column. With your selection of `subfigure` (which is by the way very old and replaced with new `subfig`) above picture is difficult to obtain, better is use of the `subcaption` packages and his `subfigure` environment, for which you can define width of environment and by this make more place for (sub)caption). See MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\title{Tree}
\author{Author}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle,draw,color=red] {} [grow'=up];
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\caption{$b^T e = 1$}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle,draw,color=red] {} [grow'=up];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$b^T e = 1$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{My subfigures}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```